# Shred this XML into name/value pairs

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an XML field in SQL Server that I need to shred. The data looks like this.

```
<tags>
  <tags name="CLAIM_VIEW_ATTYFILENO" value="04-01883" order="0" />
  <tags name="_TODAY" value="February 14, 2019" order="12" />
  <tags name="CLAIM_VIEW_ATTYFILENO" value="04-01883" order="22" />
  <tags name="CLAIM_VIEW_CURRENTBALANCE" value="$7,484.34" order="-1" />
  <tags name="@NN_SIFAMT" value="$2,993.74" order="-1" />
  <tags name="@SETTLEMENT_DATE" value="April 30th, 2019" order="24" />
</tags>
```

This query just returns NULL:

```
SELECT TAGS.node.value('@NN_SIFAMT[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS FILENO
FROM @data.nodes('/tags') AS TAGS(NODE)
```

I just need back the values.

Comment: Mark what work have you done around this. Without some sample data and what you have tried your question is going to get marked down. And welcome to SO

Comment: Sorry guys. This data lives in a field in the database. I just need a query to parse this into a table with columns that correspond to the names with the data being the values. I have tried every suggestion I can find but I am not getting back the data I expect. For example:  SELECT TAGS.node.value('@NN_SIFAMT[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS FILENO
FROM @data.nodes('/tags') AS TAGS(NODE)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to retrieve most of the values. CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY is needed because XML is in the table column. And a different XPath expression.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data)
VALUES
(N'<tags>
  <tags name="CLAIM_VIEW_ATTYFILENO" value="04-01883" order="0" />
  <tags name="_TODAY" value="February 14, 2019" order="12" />
  <tags name="CLAIM_VIEW_ATTYFILENO" value="04-01883" order="22" />
  <tags name="CLAIM_VIEW_CURRENTBALANCE" value="$7,484.34" order="-1" />
  <tags name="@NN_SIFAMT" value="$2,993.74" order="-1" />
  <tags name="@SETTLEMENT_DATE" value="April 30th, 2019" order="24" />
</tags>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
      , col.value('@name','VARCHAR(50)') AS col_name
      , col.value('@value','VARCHAR(50)') AS col_value
FROM @tbl tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.[xml_data].nodes('/tags/tags') AS tab(col);
```

> Output:

```
+----+---------------------------+-------------------+
| ID |         col_name          |     col_value     |
+----+---------------------------+-------------------+
|  1 | CLAIM_VIEW_ATTYFILENO     | 04-01883          |
|  1 | _TODAY                    | February 14, 2019 |
|  1 | CLAIM_VIEW_ATTYFILENO     | 04-01883          |
|  1 | CLAIM_VIEW_CURRENTBALANCE | $7,484.34         |
|  1 | @NN_SIFAMT                | $2,993.74         |
|  1 | @SETTLEMENT_DATE          | April 30th, 2019  |
+----+---------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm afraid I still don't understand the cross apply but I will try to get my head around it.